# passing STL container in a class to another class

Tags: c++, class, stl

I am trying to pass a STL container in a class to another class
For ex.

```
typedef std::map<std::string, int*> Container_t;
class A
{
   public:
      const Container_t * get_container() const;
   private:
      Container_t container;
};

const Container_t * A::get_container() const
{
   return &container;
}
```

And when I try to get this in another class, I get compilation error
saying 
error: argument of type ‘Container_t* (A::)()const’ does not match ‘Container_t*’

```
void foo(A * a)
{
   const Container_t * container = a->get_container();
}
```

It will be best if I can get const reference instead of pointer. but I don't want to copy the return value of function in A. So it has to be either pointer or reference. Thank you

Comment: There is no point in making this member private if you're going to expose it like this. This is just bad practice.

Comment: Your code compiles successfully on gcc 4.5.2. Are you sure that line generates an error?

Comment: They are in seperate file. That maybe why?

Comment: No, that error means you are doing something nasty. If i had to guess, i'd say your doing something like `Container c = &A::get_container`. Check the line that generates the error and paste it...

Comment: Cruise_ship.cpp:171: error: argument of type ‘const Island_container_t* (Model::)()const’ does not match ‘const Island_container_t*’
this is actual error. Think of Model as A

Comment: It looks like you're doing `somefunc(a->get_container)` rather than `somefunc(a->get_container())`, but honestly the error doesn't match the code you've shown at all so I doubt you're going to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your function signature to:

`const Container_t * get_container() const;`

The reason is that the last `const` there at the end says "calling this function and using what it returns will not change this object."  However, returning a (non-const) pointer to the member variable gives the caller freedom to change that variable, so you have to return a `const Container_t *` to ensure that the caller doesn't modify the member variable (and thereby modify the object).

Comment: Did you change it to `const Container_t *` for both the declaration (in the class) and the definition (outside the class)?  If you didn't, then of course it didn't work.  The declaration and the definition have to match.

Comment: What's your real code then, because this would solve the problem if this were your real code.